# How to intercept Moya request and return failure response without sending the request at all

Tags: ios, swift, moya

I'm using Moya library to handle networking layer, and I already have a custom plugin that add an authentication token to the header.

What I want to do is to make this plugin cancel the request and return a failure response (or throw an error) if the token is not available yet.

P.S. I extended the protocol `TargetType` to add extra variable that indicates if the target needs authentication or not, so I need to access these data to determine if the authentication token is needed in the header or not.

this is a snapshot of my custom plugin:

```
struct AuthTokenPlugin: PluginType {
    let tokenClosure:()->String?

    func prepare(_ request: URLRequest, target: TargetType) -> URLRequest {
        guard let target = target as? AuthorizebleTargetType, target.needsAuth else {
            return request
        }

        guard let token = tokenClosure() else {
            // Here where a failure response will be triggered or an error should be thrown  
            return ......
        }

        var request = request
        request.addValue( "Token " + token, forHTTPHeaderField:"Authorization")
        return request
    }
}
```

P.S.2: throwing an error is not a good practice and it is not possible because the enclosing function "prepare(_:target:)" is not declared 'throws'.

Comment: Why throwing an error is not a good practice? You may prefer returning an `Optional URLRequest`.

Comment: not a good practice because it is logically a normal failure of the response, not an exception (like JSON parsing error) to the regular logic.

`Optional URLRequest` might solve the issue but it is not possible too since it is not declared optional in PluginType protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that we can implement such logic with usage of `protocol TargetType` in cause his methods don't return Bool values and are not throw-marked.

Take a look at `MoyaProvider` init parameters. There is a `requestClosure` param in it. You can copy-paste and replace this parameter's default implementation with your own implementation which will check authorization header of `Endpoint`.

Default implementation of this closure:

```
final class func defaultRequestMapping(for endpoint: Endpoint, closure: RequestResultClosure) {
        do {
            let urlRequest = try endpoint.urlRequest()
            closure(.success(urlRequest))
        } catch MoyaError.requestMapping(let url) {
            closure(.failure(MoyaError.requestMapping(url)))
        } catch MoyaError.parameterEncoding(let error) {
            closure(.failure(MoyaError.parameterEncoding(error)))
        } catch {
            closure(.failure(MoyaError.underlying(error, nil)))
        }
    }
```

**UPD** with my comment:

I suggest to check that if `Endpoint` has header with key “Authorization”, but it’s value is empty string, then call `closure` parameter with `.failure` case in `requestClosure`

Comment: Thank you for your response.
but I wasn't complete in my question.
from what I understand, this `requestClosure` has the `Endpoint` object not a `TargetType`.
but I need the `TargetType` object to determine if the authentication token is needed in the header or not.
I updated my question with the details.

Comment: You can check that if `Endpont` has header with key “Authorization”, but it’s value is empty string, then call `closure` parameter with `.failure` case in `requestClosure`

Comment: Thanks again.  Can you edit you answer to include this suggestion, so others can get the full answer without reading comments